# Entity Framework 6. Automatically truncate string fields that exceed DB Field Length

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Firstly, why do this? In production system if data comes in that is too big for the DB, you may want to keep running and accept the data loss if the fields are not critical, and there will be bigger problems if the record is not inserted.

I have this working with the following code but it is ugly as hell having to reflect over private .net framework properties.

Surely there is a better way to do this?
I saw following code on another posting to load the metadata but it does not work. The Types loaded this way do not have the database field lengths populated. We generate model from DB. That way we do not ever have to make manual adjustments to entity model ourselves (the DB first method).

```
var metaDataWorkspace = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace;
var edmTypes = metaDataWorkspace.GetItems<EdmType>(DataSpace.OSpace);
```

The Method with the logic is in AutoTruncateStringToMaxLength() below.

has following usings:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Validation;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm;
```

code which sits in partial entity class (e.g. public partial class MyEntities):

```
public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        try
        {
            this.AutoTruncateStringToMaxLength();
            return base.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
        {
            List<string> errorMessages = new List<string>();
            foreach (DbEntityValidationResult validationResult in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                string entityName = validationResult.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name;
                foreach (DbValidationError error in validationResult.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    errorMessages.Add(entityName + "." + error.PropertyName + ": " + error.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }

            // Join the list to a single string.
            var fullErrorMessage = string.Join("; ", errorMessages);

            // Combine the original exception message with the new one.
            var exceptionMessage = string.Concat(ex.Message, " The validation errors are: ", fullErrorMessage);

            // Throw a new DbEntityValidationException with the improved exception message.
            throw new DbEntityValidationException(exceptionMessage, ex.EntityValidationErrors);
        }
    }

    private void AutoTruncateStringToMaxLength()
    {
        var entries = this?.ChangeTracker?.Entries();
        if (entries == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        //********** EDM type from here does not work. MaxLength properties are not set ***************** //
        //var metaDataWorkspace = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace;
        //var edmTypes = metaDataWorkspace.GetItems<EdmType>(DataSpace.OSpace);

        ReadOnlyMetadataCollection<EdmMember> memberMetaDataProperties = null;
        string currentloadedEdmType = null;
        foreach (var entry in entries)
        {
            var internalEntry = entry.GetType().GetProperty("InternalEntry", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(entry);
            var edmType = (EdmType)internalEntry.GetType().GetProperty("EdmEntityType", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(internalEntry);

            if (edmType != null)
            {
                if (currentloadedEdmType == null || edmType.Name != currentloadedEdmType)
                {
                    currentloadedEdmType = edmType.Name;
                    //seems slow to load (in debug) so cache just in case there is performance issue
                    memberMetaDataProperties = (ReadOnlyMetadataCollection<EdmMember>)edmType.MetadataProperties.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Members").Value;
                }

                entry.Entity.GetType().GetProperties().ToList().ForEach(p =>
                {
                    var matchingMemberMetaData = memberMetaDataProperties.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == p.Name);
                    if (matchingMemberMetaData != null && matchingMemberMetaData.BuiltInTypeKind.ToString() == "EdmProperty")
                    {
                        var edmProperty = (EdmProperty)matchingMemberMetaData;
                        if (edmProperty.MaxLength.HasValue && edmProperty.TypeName == "String")
                        {
                            string value = (p.GetValue(entry.Entity) ?? "").ToString();
                            if (value.Length > edmProperty.MaxLength.Value)
                            {
                                // oops. Its too Long, so truncate it.
                                p.SetValue(entry.Entity, value.Substring(value.Length - edmProperty.MaxLength.Value));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have used the following solution successfully using an extension method. 
 https://medium.com/@paullorica/automatically-truncate-strings-in-an-ef-core-entity-based-on-maxlength-property-93e17ea7cd43

Answer (score 1):

EF Core has a better metadata API.  EG

```
var q = from e in this.Model.GetEntityTypes()
        from p in e.GetProperties()
        where p.ClrType == typeof(string)
        select new { EntityName = e.Name, PropertyName = p.Name, MaxLength = p.GetMaxLength() };
```

Answer (score 0):

This was super-helpful!  You got us most of the way there... the main fix to avoid using reflection is to fix that metadata stuff you'd commented out.  You should've been using *EntityType* (rather than *EDMType*), and searching in the *C*Space (conceptual/model space); not the *O*Space.  I was then able to use your code as a starting point to get to this.

Since we use multiple EF models in the same project, I wrote this as an internal extension method, so it can be called from *any* DbContext, rather than a private member of a *specific* DbContext.  I also added code for logging whenever a field is truncated.  The "GlobalLogger" lines just point to the logger *we* use--you can either *remove* them, or update them to work with your *own* logger:

```
internal static void AutoTruncateStrings(this DbContext dbContext)
        {
            try
            {
                var metaDataWorkspace = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace;
                var modelMetadata = metaDataWorkspace.GetItems<EntityType>(DataSpace.CSpace);
                var entries = dbContext?.ChangeTracker?.Entries();
                if (entries == null) return;
                foreach (var entry in entries)
                {
                    if (entry.State != EntityState.Added && entry.State != EntityState.Modified) continue; // Only process added or modified entries.
                    var efEntityName = entry.Entity.GetType().FullName;
                    if (efEntityName.StartsWith("System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies")) efEntityName = entry.Entity.GetType().BaseType.FullName;
                    foreach (var propertyName in entry.CurrentValues.PropertyNames)
                    {
                        var entityMetadata = modelMetadata.Single(e => e.FullName == efEntityName);
                        var propMetadata = entityMetadata.Properties[propertyName];
                        if (propMetadata.TypeName.ToLowerInvariant() != "string" || propMetadata.MaxLength == null) continue;
                        if (entry.CurrentValues[propertyName]?.ToString().Length > propMetadata.MaxLength)
                        {
                            // Truncate value, and log that it was truncated.
                            string truncatedValue = Common.Left(entry.CurrentValues[propertyName].ToString(), propMetadata.MaxLength.Value);
                            GlobalLogger.Logger.LogWarning($"A string value on an Entity Framework entity had to be truncated because it exceeded its  maximum length." +
                                $"\n\n" +
                                $"Entity: {efEntityName}\n" +
                                $"Entity Key: [{string.Join(", ", entityMetadata.KeyProperties.Select(kp => kp.Name))}] = [{string.Join(", ", entityMetadata.KeyProperties.Select(kp => entry.CurrentValues[kp.Name].ToString()))}]\n" +
                                $"Property: {propertyName}\n" +
                                $"Maximum Length: {propMetadata.MaxLength.Value}\n" +
                                $"Original Length: {entry.CurrentValues[propertyName].ToString().Length}\n" +
                                $"Original Value: {entry.CurrentValues[propertyName]}\n" +
                                $"Truncated Value: {truncatedValue}");
                            entry.CurrentValues[propertyName] = truncatedValue;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                GlobalLogger.Logger.LogError("An unhandled exception occurred while trying to auto-truncate Entity Framework entity string properties.  Automatic truncation will be skipped for the remainder of this SaveChanges() batch.", ex);
            }
        }
```

Comment: In EF Core, you might be able to use a value converter.

Comment: Thanks--I forgot to mention that I added this despite David Browne mentioning above that EF Core might be better, because we're still a .NET Framework shop, and I suspect many others still are, too. :)

Comment: Thanks for the code sample.  I'm not seeing where _entitiesMissingFromMetadata is defined.  Can you please show us how to build that string?

Comment: Ooops!  Sorry about that--I actually meant to remove that.  I've removed it now.  I'd love to get my first upvote from you! :)